# a stop job is running for /dev/mapper/name (xxxs / no limit

Tags: redhat

running rhel 8.8, all of  sudden the systems will not reboot properly. The console show the message

```
a stop job is running for /dev/mapper/name (xxxs / no limit)
```

This device is a luks container mounted as a non-root disk. The disk gets auto-decrypted using nbde clevis + tang. This works perfectly. When rebooting, the server hangs on the message above.

I have tried adding to fstab and crypttab the options x-systemd.mount-timeout=90s, the device gets mapped correctly on boot, but there is no timeout limit even after several reboots and consequent resets.

The device is the datastore for kvm vms. If I manually shutdown the vms, and run systemd-umount /var/lib/libvirt/images where the device is mounted, a subsequent reboot works perfectly fine.

Any idea on how to troubleshoot this? How can I add a limit to this job?

Comment: as i dont see that you had done any research as described in [ask] one of a Google search found a [way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1033569/luks-clevis-fstab-a-start-job-is-running-for-dev-mapper-encryptedfs-device-5m) on the college of askubuntu.com ;)

Comment: start != stop. I had already seen that question, but as I had stated, the devices are mounting perfectly. The problem is when rebooting.

Comment: read carefully the article, there is also as I seen a timeout action. did you tried it?

Comment: after adding the x-systemd-device-timeout=xxs to /etc/fstab the reboot hangs in the exactly same way; unsurprising, because the solution to the other start issue was to add _netdev to crypttab, which is needed for non-root disks and automatic decryption. This is not the issue, the issue is a hanging shutdown/reboot, not boot.

Comment: found a workaround, in the reboot.target there is a settinig JobTimeoutSec=30min, and indeed, after 30 min, the system reboots. So I will create a local reboot.target with a lower setting, that should do it.

Comment: I might have an idea what's the root cause. But let me confirm first: do you use `nofail` and/or `x-systemd.automount` in the corresponding fstab entry? (Actually, it would be best if you can share the `systemctl show` output for the corresponding mount unit (`var-lib-libvirt-images.mount`, I suppose). In particular, the `Before=` line.)

Comment: no 'Before=' in the output of systemctl show mount unit (nice command, I had not remembered to use it). The fstab options are just _netdev,defaults now, it works with the downgraded systemd rpm. Sorry for not posting the output of the commands, but this system is not accessible from the system I use in serverfault.

Comment: If there's no Before= at all, probably you have entered the wrong mount unit name. (I should have suggested systemctl cat instead.) So were you using `nofail`, `x-systemd.automount` and/or  `_netdev` when you had problem with the newer version? Also, you are using fstab entry right? Or is it actually a manually written mount unit? (Would be nice if you can also check with systemctl cat whether the what is the /dev/disk/by-uuid/* path, assuming you are using UUID=* in an fstab entry.)

Comment: _netdev,defaults only, Indeed, I was missing the b in libvirt, Before=umount.target remote-fs.target

Answer (score 1):

while I wait for an official answer from red hat, I found a working situation:

```
systemctl edit reboot.target
```

modify JobTimeoutSec=30min for the desired timeout in your case. Reload systemd and reboot. This fixes this problem for now.

It turns out this bug was already known: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=2220954. Fix is to downgrade systemd (version on bugzilla). The real solution will be waiting for a fix from redhat. So in the meantime, if you come accross this, either override the reboot target or downgrade systemd until this is fixed by red hat.

Comment: remember that you need to accept your answer in 24 hours ;) I've up voted as support